# Deserialize OData V2 Array with JSON.NET

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, odata

I am trying to deserialize the following response from an OData V2 service using Newtonsoft JSON.NET.

However I am getting the following exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'Newtonsoft.Json.TestConsole.City[]' because the type
>   requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix
>   this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or
>   change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g.
>   not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array
>   or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
>   JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to
>   deserialize from a JSON object. Path 'Cities.results', line 6,
>   position 12.

It seems to me that I need to transform the respone and remove the results token before deserializing.

Do you have any ideas how I could do that?

This is the OData V2 response:

```
{
   "__metadata":{
      "uri":"https://www.myuri.com",
      "type":"OdataWebServiceExample.Countrys"
   },
   "Name":"usa",
   "Cities":{
      "results":[
         {
            "__metadata":{
               "uri":"https://www.myuri.com",
               "type":"OdataWebServiceExample.Citys"
            },
            "Name":"new york",
            "Persons":{
               "results":[
                  {
                     "__metadata":{
                        "uri":"https://www.myuri.com",
                        "type":"OdataWebServiceExample.Persons"
                     },
                     "Name":"joe dalton"
                  },
                  {
                     "__metadata":{
                        "uri":"https://www.myuri.com",
                        "type":"OdataWebServiceExample.Persons"
                     },
                     "Name":"jack dalton"
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This is the corresponding C# class:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Newtonsoft.Json.TestConsole
{
    [DataContract (Name="Countrys")]
    public class Country
    {
        [DataMember (Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set;}

        [DataMember (Name = "Cities")]
        public City[] Cities { get; set;}

        public Country ()
        {
        }
    }

    [DataContract (Name="Citys")]
    public class City
    {
        [DataMember (Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set;}


        [DataMember (Name = "Persons")]
        public Person[] Persons { get; set;}

        public City ()
        {
        }
    }

    [DataContract (Name="Persons")]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember (Name = "Name")]
        public string Name { get; set;}

        public Person ()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Cities` is an **object** which **contains an array** in your JSON. You're treating `Cities` as an array instead of an object. Create a class that wraps the `results` array inside of it.

Comment: Also (and I'm not sure if this affects this problem) but your `City` class has decorator misspelled "Cities" as "Citys".  Fixing that, might fix another bug as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using the JSON example that you provided and using the "Paste JSON as Classes" feature in VS2012, I got the following classes (I removed the _metadata sections as it seems you are not using them and can be ignored)

```
public class ODataResponse
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Cities Cities { get; set; }
}

public class Cities
{
  public City[] results { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Persons Persons { get; set; }
}

public class Persons
{
  public Person[] results { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Using those classes, you can then deserialize the given JSON with the code

```
using (JsonReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(inputText)))
{
  JsonSerializer seri = new JsonSerializer();
  ODataResponse output = seri.Deserialize(reader, typeof(ODataResponse)) as ODataResponse;
}
```

The defined classes resolve the problems identified by both GrawCube and RLH in the comments.